# How to declare a C# Record Type?

Tags: c#, language-features, c#-7.0

I read [on a blog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1131035/New-Features-of-Csharp) that C# 7 will feature record types

```
class studentInfo(string StudentFName, string StudentMName, string StudentLName);
```

However when I tried it, I get these errors

> CS0116    A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or
>   methods
>   CS1022    Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>   CS1514    { expected

How is this supposed to work?

**Update: it's a feature of C# 9**
 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/

Comment: The link you referenced says that this is not implemented yet `Update 22/07/2016: Records are probably not coming in C# 7, but will have to wait until the next version (supposedly c# 8)`

Comment: The provided [C# 9 link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) uses the no longer valid `data class` dev notation - [as of .NET 5.0 RC 1 that has already been changed to `record`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-1/). [Official (updated) docu also uses `record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Update:

[C# 9 now contains record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types).

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }

    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```

### Old answer:

Record types are not (yet) implemented in C#. See the proposal in the official GitHub repository:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md

Discuss or vote at https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39

Comment: @JeremyThompson I guess someone flagged it? Wasn't me, I went through my history and it's not there. Maybe the person who edited it? Does it really matter?

Comment: Is this c# 9 feature available in any of the .NET 5 previews?

Comment: @IainGalloway it is since at least [.NET 5.0 RC 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-1/) though with the `record` syntax instead the old `data class` proposal. In [LINQPad6](https://twitter.com/linqpad/status/1315574927982903297) you can even fiddle with C# 9 without having .net 5 installed (if you have .net core 3.1 installed - either 5 or 3.1 is required for that feature). From 6.10 Release Notes: *Just go to Edit | Preferences > Query and tick the Enable C# 9 Preview checkbox.*

Answer (score 8):

Record types were on the roadmap for C# 7.0, but were ultimately delayed until a later version of the language.

To quote Mads Torgersen in reply to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/),

> [Primary constructors] are still on the radar, **along with the related concept of record types (which we considered for C# 7.0)**, and I am hopeful that we can land on a better design – maybe one that encompasses both.

As of C# 7's release, the [GitHub proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md) for this language feature still indicates that the implementation is "In Progress."

Comment: > Record type, an immutable value type, is another feature being developed. https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/06/csharp-mads-torgersen-qcon

Answer (score 6):

[**Rewritten to reflect the current state of things**]

To add to the other answers, you can easily track when C# features are pencilled in to appear in C# these days. For example, the [Champion "Records"](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39) issue shows the state of thinking around records. Records is now scheduled for C# 9. But that feature was previously touted for C# 6, C# 7 and C# 8 too, so it remains only an aspiration.

Answer (score 4):

> Prior to C# 7.0 you declare classes like this:

Although record types have not been implemented yet in C# 7.0 (as detailed by the other answers), you *can* shorten your code by using [read-only auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-enhancements), introduced in C# 6.0:

```
public class studentInfo
{
    public string StudentFName { get; }
    public string StudentMName { get; }
    public string StudentLName { get; }

    public studentInfo(string strFN, string strMN, string strLN)
    {
        StudentFName = strFN;
        StudentMName = strMN;
        StudentLName = strLN;
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately requires each member to be written *three times* (as a property, as a constructor parameter, and as an assignment in the constructor). I recommend using T4 to generate these immutable POCOs in future (to help prevent bugs where you didn't do the right assignment in the constructor).

Comment: @Dai: The latter two can be automated by using Visual Studio's ["Generate constructor" quick action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-constructor?view=vs-2019). That said, I'm also looking forward to getting rid of all that boilerplate code and having "real" record types.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way if you're looking for record-like, lazy way of implementing constructors using currently available C# 7 functionality:

```
class Lazystructor
{
    int a;
    float b;
    WebClient c;

    public Lazystructor(int a, float b, WebClient c)
        =>  (this.a, this.b, this.c) = (a, b, c);
}
```

**A bit of consideration if you're using this on a performance-sensitive scenario, as it's a process of ValueTuple creation and extraction.**

Comment: That's quite creative.

Comment: I'll give you an update for the creativity, but I am not a fan of this syntax. The whole point of records is to simplify the declaration of simple types but I think people would find this confusing.

Answer (score 2):

C#9 is now available and records with it.

Here are some example:

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; init; }

    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```

With the use of *positional records* (and inheritance):

```
public record Teacher(string FirstName, string LastName,
    string Subject)
    : Person(FirstName, LastName);

public sealed record Student(string FirstName,
    string LastName, int Level)
    : Person(FirstName, LastName);

var person = new Person("Bill", "Wagner");

var (first, last) = person;
Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(last);
```

Finally, records support with-expressions. A with-expression instructs the compiler to create a copy of a record, but with specified properties modified:

```
Person brother = person with { FirstName = "Paul" };
```

Everything you need to know about every new features including records [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9)

Comment: Link only answers end up on the time machine. if you are after points/rep take the time to write a decent answer for years to come.