# passing a parameter to a class declaration in C# 8

Tags: c#, rider

Since C# 8, we can do something like:

```
public class MyClass(int a)
{
    // note, this is NOT the constructor, but the class declaration
}
```

how does this work?

with C#7, it was marked as an experimental feature; but I can't find documentation about it.
Is is still considered experimental with C# 8?

I am seeing this:

[image]

Comment: "*Since C# 8, we can do something like:*" -- are you sure about that? [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEDMACFAmDBZATwGEAbaKACgEsA7GDCASgFgAoAbzY24wHpeMNAPbwANBhgALKlAwyMAOQDyAFQmS4GAMZCasBAFctMIQnHAD9KZpwYAJnC1kEEGFV1sAvkA==)

Comment: Where have you read about this class declaration? Can you provide a link to the document?

Comment: The [C# Language Feature Status Page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md) doesn't indicate that this will be in C# 8.

Comment: Yes, this isn't implemented yet. It's for a future version of C# (maybe). The feature [is called a Record type](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/candidate-features-for-c-sharp-9/).

Comment: I added a screenshot; I can't compile it because it is apparently not how it's supposed to be used, but with C# 7.3, it is flagged as experimental and with C# 8 not anymore. This is using Rider (Resharper), on a Mac.

Comment: What's the problem that this would solve?

Comment: What is `public class MyClass(int a)` supposed to do? What is the name of this *feature*?

Comment: @OlivierRogier It's called a *Record*.

Comment: This does not compile for me in a .NET Core 3 application (which uses C# 8) -- are you using a preview version? This used to be floated as "primary constructors" in drafts of C# 6, and is currently being worked on as "[records](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md)". I'm pretty sure this is still experimental since it's not part of the current list of proposals, but given the fact that we haven't been granted actual, definite language specs since C# 5 it's hard to tell. :-P

Comment: I have no idea, I just discovered that it is flagged as experimental; so there is something that exists and its status got changed between version 7.3 and 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a C# Record Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105895/how-to-declare-a-c-sharp-record-type)

Comment: @OlivierRogier, I think you're right! I wonder why the status changed between 7.3 and 8 though; it's not flagged as experimental in my version of 8

Comment: I think you'll need to ask JetBrains - allowing this feature to compile, and flagging it as experimental, is all a Rider thing. I'm not aware that Visual Studio has done any of that.

Comment: @canton7, I will open a ticket with them to see what's up

Comment: Note that whatever Rider/Resharper has to say on the matter is not definitive; both are likely to trail actual developments in CoreFX/Roslyn. If anything this should probably be floated as a bug there, since actual production versions of the compiler that people can use don't offer this, not even as an experimental feature.

Comment: I found this totally randomly: I wanted to add quickly a parameter to a constructor and seeing the same name, I started to type it in the class declaration :)